# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set

Tags: javascript, java, scheduled-tasks

I have a condition to make some schedule send email but I am getting below error while implementing the code.

This my error

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.getRekananByCurrStat(Unknown Source)
    at com.promise3.scheduler.VendorScheduler.unblacklistAutoScheduler(VendorScheduler.java:122)
    at com.promise3.scheduler.VendorScheduler.executeVendorScheduler(VendorScheduler.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:321)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:111)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.promise.interceptor.SoapHeaderInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapHeaderInterceptor.java:25)
    at com.promise.interceptor.SoapHeaderInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapHeaderInterceptor.java:1)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Are you sure the `javascript` tag should be on this question?  It appears to be related to Java only...  Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!  As a new user you might want to review [ask] - looking at this question I feel like it is perhaps unclear, but perhaps someone more familiar with Java will understand and be able to answer.

Comment: It does look like Java and I suspect that even a Java dev would like some context including maybe a sample of some of the code being run.  Adding some code would greatly increase your chances of getting a quality response!

Comment: The problem appears to be in a jax ws webservice client (it's a Java webservice), specifically in `com.promise.interceptor.SoapHeaderInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapHeaderInterceptor.java:25) ` . 
findJar returns nothing on this class. So I believe it is a custom message interceptor developed by your team (or inside your company). Try debugging it or reading it's code to find out what causes the NullPointerException.